# How to host a Botpress Chatbot in Heroku platform after creating it?

Tags: heroku, artificial-intelligence, nlu, botpress

My Botpress chatbot is ready to get deployed. I have gone through the documentation provided in the Botpress official website about how to deploy it in the Heroku platform but couldn't figure out mot of the things. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy Botpress on Heroku using this link: https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/botpress/botpress

The deployment uses master branch of oficial repo and also provision an free postgres db along with the app.

After deployment was made I used Import / Export of Botpress to move my flows from dev to prod.